# Can I safely delete build\tmp\expandedArchives folder in my Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, explorer

I am unable to move my Gradle based project to another location, as Windows keeps giving me the error "file path too long", though I see I can work on that long file name inside Android Studio without a hitch. I found that the contents of this folder are to blame:

`AndroidProject \app\build\tmp\expandedArchives`

The expanded archives looks like it opens up all the dependencies of the app over here with very long folder & file names. Some examples here:

```
\app\build\tmp\expandedArchives\classes.jar_7qh18304vjdra8i85sw4cqx14\android\support\compat...
\app\build\tmp\expandedArchives\picasso-2.5.2.jar_w4l5rlwig2lthm63umx5rllh\com\picasso\...
```

Given that it is stored inside `tmp`, can I safely delete this folder & move my project folder? Will it create any problem resurrecting my project from the new location?

Comment: Everything in the `build` folder and `app\build folder` is generated during a build. You can delete it.

Comment: Ok so after deleting the `tmp` or `build` folder, when I reintroduce the project from a new location by clicking `Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)`, will Android Studio rebuild all the dependencies & the `build` folder automatically? Will I be able to readily test run my project out of the box, just as before?

Comment: You don't import it again, just choose the `open Android Studio project` something like that